# LLVM assertion failure using AliasAnalysis in Module pass

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I am running into an issue trying to use AliasAnalysis from within a module pass (LLVM 3.4). This seems to be a fairly common issue with two main solutions, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

With the following simple test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int gX;

void f() {
  gX = 1;
}

int main() {
  printf("Hello.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled like this: `clang++ -O0 -c -emit-llvm -o test.bc test.cpp`

And my simple pass:

```
class DebugPass : public ModulePass {
public:
  static char ID;
  DebugPass() : ModulePass(ID) {}

  virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
    AU.setPreservesAll();
    AU.addRequired<AliasAnalysis>();
  }

  virtual bool runOnModule(Module &M) {
    for (Module::iterator fit = M.begin(), fite = M.end(); fit != fite; ++fit) {
      Function *F = fit;
      if (F->isDeclaration()) continue;
      errs() << "Getting AA for " << F->getName() << "\n";
      AliasAnalysis &AA = getAnalysis<AliasAnalysis>(*F);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
char DebugPass::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<DebugPass> X("testdebug", "Debugging pass", false, false);
```

And by invoking my pass like this: `opt -load ../Debug+Asserts/lib/TestLib.dylib -basicaa -testdebug < test.bc > /dev/null`

I am seeing the following assertion failure:

```
Getting AA for _Z1fv
Assertion failed: (FPP && "Unable to find on the fly pass"), function getOnTheFlyPass, file LegacyPassManager.cpp, line 1682.
...
6  opt                      0x0000000102e5ba62 abort + 18
7  opt                      0x0000000102e5ba41 __assert_rtn + 129
8  opt                      0x0000000102d94820 (anonymous namespace)::MPPassManager::getOnTheFlyPass(llvm::Pass*, void const*, llvm::Function&) + 144
9  opt                      0x0000000102d949cf non-virtual thunk to (anonymous namespace)::MPPassManager::getOnTheFlyPass(llvm::Pass*, void const*, llvm::Function&) + 63
10 opt                      0x0000000102d8ed4e llvm::AnalysisResolver::findImplPass(llvm::Pass*, void const*, llvm::Function&) + 78
11 TestLib.dylib           0x0000000104ba9bac llvm::AliasAnalysis& llvm::Pass::getAnalysisID<llvm::AliasAnalysis>(void const*, llvm::Function&) + 236
12 TestLib.dylib           0x0000000104b9eef6 llvm::AliasAnalysis& llvm::Pass::getAnalysis<llvm::AliasAnalysis>(llvm::Function&) + 134
13 TestLib.dylib           0x0000000104bdc287 DebugPass::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 215
```

Can anyone offer some insight into what is going wrong?

Edit: Here is the pass structure via `-debug-pass=Structure`:

```
Pass Arguments:  -targetlibinfo -datalayout -notti -basictti -x86tti -no-aa -basicaa -testdebug -preverify -domtree -verify
Target Library Information
Data Layout
No target information
Target independent code generator's TTI
X86 Target Transform Info
No Alias Analysis (always returns 'may' alias)
Basic Alias Analysis (stateless AA impl)
  ModulePass Manager
    Debugging pass
    FunctionPass Manager
      Preliminary module verification
      Dominator Tree Construction
      Module Verifier
    Bitcode Writer
```

Is it significant that my debugging pass occurs before the FunctionPass manager? I am not practiced in interpreting the pass structure output.

Comment: I suspect you need to include the pass in the `LinkAllPasses` list.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, can you elaborate a little? Do I really need to modify the LLVM tree in order to implement a pass that uses AliasAnalysis?

Comment: To be fair, I don't know. I've only written a compiler that uses standard passes. I tried adding your pass to the compiler, and it "works" in the sense that it doesn't crash/assert/etc.

Comment: Ah, no, it's not working (it just wasn't enabled by default when I added it). In other words, I can repro your problem.

Comment: The problem is clearly that it can't find the AliasAnalysis implementation. But I'm not sure why... It's too late here now, I'll have a look in the morning.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand - I see it being installed in the passmanager, and then it can't find it. Will try adding some debug prints in good places tomorrow.

Comment: I didn't see your comment yesterday, but yes, I think the fact that your pass is a ModulePass rather than a FunctionPass is key - I will try this out.

Comment: That changes the error message, but still doesn't work.

Comment: `getAnalysis<AliasAnalysis>()`, not `getAnalysis<AliasAnalysis>(*F)`, seems the right way to call it because `BasicAliasAnalysis` (`-basicaa`) was a module pass until LLVM 3.8: `BasicAliasAnalysis` inherited from `ImmutablePass`, which in turn inherited from `ModulePass`: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/release_37/lib/Analysis/BasicAliasAnalysis.cpp#L437 https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/release_37/include/llvm/Pass.h#L262

Comment: I am trying to move my code which uses llvm3.6.2 to llvm3.8.1 and I am facing the same issue. So @proc-self-maps, were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue. Is there any solutions or explanations as of 2020? @tdenniston